# How to convert histogram into simple plot using marker?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted a histogram. But I want to use its data to plot a simple graph showing data points using marker. But for this i need values on x-axis and y-axis. For y-axis I can use n in the following code but then what will be the x-axis values? I can not choose bins as x-axis because it returns bin edges.

```
x= np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,5,5,4,4.3,10])   
n,bins,patches=plt.hist(x,bins=5,density=True)
print("n is: ",n)
plt.xlim([0,6])
plt.xlabel('s')
plt.ylabel('P(s)')`
#Result
#n is:  [0.28125, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.,0.03125]

#Simple graph:
#plt.plot(?,n,marker='.')
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would use `range(len(n))` as `x-axis`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to something like this?

```py
x= np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,5,5,4,4.3,10])
n,bins,patches=plt.hist(x,bins=5,density=True, alpha=0.6)

plt.xlabel('s')
plt.ylabel('P(s)')
plt.scatter(bins[:-1]+ 0.5*(bins[1:] - bins[:-1]), n, marker='o', c='red', s=40, alpha=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes But I want to plot curve using these red dots, Beside I want to know what is the purpose of alpha? In documentation i didn't find it and what is the purpose of this last line with s etc? plt.scatter(bins[:-1]+ 0.5*(bins[1:] - bins[:-1]), n, marker='o', c='red', s=40, alpha=1)

Comment: alpha is to make the bars more transparent with respect the scatter plot

Comment: but use plot function instead of scatter, if you want to join the points

Answer (score 1):

I would use `range(len(n))` as x-axis

```
 plt.plot(range(len(n)), n, marker='.')
```

but you can get the same withouth x-axis values

```
 plt.plot(n, marker='.')
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x= np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,5,5,4,4.3,10])  
n,bins,patches=plt.hist(x,bins=5,density=True)
plt.show()
print("n is: ",n)
plt.xlim([0,6])
plt.xlabel('s')
plt.ylabel('P(s)')
#Result
#n is:  [0.28125, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.,0.03125]

#Simple graph:
plt.plot(range(len(n)), n, marker='.')
plt.show()

plt.plot(n, marker='.')
plt.show()
```

---

**EDIT:** you can also use `bins` to calculate `x-axis`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,5,5,4,4.3,10])  
n, bins, patches=plt.hist(x,bins=5,density=True)
plt.show()

#Simple graph:
#X = [(a+b)/2 for a,b in zip(bins, bins[1:])]
X = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:])/2
Y = n
plt.plot(X, Y, marker='.')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: But using simple range(len(n)) x-axis ranges from 0 to 5.

Comment: then use different range - ie `range(1, len(n)+1)` and you get 1..6

Comment: I have shown in the second plot that  if I plot using plt,plot(np.arange(len(n),n)) I get different values from expected. If I use plt.xlim(0,5) it crops last points. Can I Plot all these 30 points using x-axis range  from zero to 5?

Comment: originally you wanted to plot values from `n` (histogram) which has only 5 points, not 30 points. And I don't see list with 30 points which you show on new plot - so I don't know how you get expected plot. If you have list with 30 points then you can use `plt.plot(range(len(new_list)), new_list)` or shorter `plt.plot(new_list)` and it will use `range(len(new_list))` in  x-axis automatically.

Comment: I added code which use `bins` to calculate values for `x-axis`